# How to use CSS of another element?

Tags: css

I have a class like this

```
.mydiv a {
    color: #014BA4;
}
```

How can I use this class for the `span` element ? (**Without adding/modifying the CSS file - I have no right to do**)

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <a href="mylink.html">This text is #014BA4</a>
    <span>How can I use the above class</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `.mydiv, .mydiv a {color:#014BA4;}` the `<span>` inherits the `color`.

Comment: just change the selector to `.mydiv a, .mydiv span`?

Comment: @Hashem might work, although you don't know if `.mydiv` itself already has a different color. But the inheritance is certainly worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

A terrible solution, but desperate times call for desperate measures; If you wrap your span in an anchor tag with the href attribute set to # and then stop the default behaviour...

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <a href="mylink.html">This text is #014BA4</a>
    <span><a href="#" onclick="return false;">How can I use the above class</a></span>
</div>
```

You would never normally do this but if it has to be done and you absolutely can't edit your css file then it's the only way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to this**

```css
.mydiv span, .mydiv a{
    color:#014BA4;
}
```

if you used to all element inner `.mydiv` than used to **this css**

```css
.mydiv{
    color:#014BA4;
}
```

Comment: -1 because `*` = bad! A lot of elements inherit the color anyway.

Comment: As `*` is the subject of the selector, it's not a good suggestion whereas there're better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS as mentioned below :

```
.mydiv a,.mydiv span {
    color:#014BA4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.mySpan,.mydiv a {
        color:#014BA4;
    }

<div class="mydiv">
    <a href="mylink.html">This text is #014BA4 </a>
    <span class="mySpan">How can I use the above class</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add the styles to all spans

```
.mydiv a, span {
    color:#014BA4;
}
```

to add this to a particular span

```
.mydiv a,.mydiv span {
    color:#014BA4;
}
```

and apply the class to the span 
    asdf

Comment: Is there any way to not modify the css? For example, other elements (not "a") want to use this style?

Comment: no the current css in the question will only be applicable to ancor tags in the div that has a class 'mydiv'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.mydiv a,.mydiv {
    color:#014BA4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just `.mydiv span` would do the trick

```
.mydiv span{
    color:#014BA4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make **Each Next** `<span>` after `<a>` with the same stile:

```
.mydiv a,
.mydiv a + span {
    color: #014BA4;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/verber/F8CZF/13/